# widgets misbehaving while being displaced in tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

so i was trying to create a function(hover_zoom) which could enlarge a tkinter widget on hover, which i have but its misbehaving quite a lot

you might have to run this in order to see whats going on, just hover over the red block

PS: sorry im doing something stupid here its my first question on stack and i've also just started with programming
any sort of advice or solution is welcome

```
import customtkinter
import threading
import itertools
import decimal

def frange(x, y, jump):
    if x<y:
        while x<y:
            yield float(x)
            x = decimal.Decimal(x)+decimal.Decimal(jump)
    elif x>y:
        while x>y:
            yield float(x)
            x = decimal.Decimal(x)+decimal.Decimal(jump)

def dfly(widget,target_x,target_y,speed):
    t1=threading.Thread(target=lambda:dfly_main(widget,target_x,target_y,speed))
    t1.start()
dfly_main_global=1
def dfly_main(widget,target_x,target_y,speed):
    global dfly_main_global
    if dfly_main_global==1:
        dfly_main_global=0

        init_x=widget.winfo_x()
        init_y=widget.winfo_y()
        diff_x=float(target_x-init_x)
        diff_y=float(target_y-init_y)
        time=(((diff_x**2)+(diff_y**2))**(1/2))*speed

        print(time)
        for frame in frange(1,time,time/abs(time)):
            widget.forget()
            widget.place(x=init_x+(frame*(diff_x/time)),y=init_y+(frame*(diff_y/time)))

        dfly_main_global=1

def hover_zoom(widget,zoom,speed):
    t2=threading.Thread(target=lambda:hover_zoom_main(widget,zoom,speed))
    t2.start()
def hover_zoom_main(widget,zoom,speed):
    width=widget.cget(attribute_name='width')
    height=widget.cget(attribute_name='height')

    dfly(widget,widget.winfo_x()-((width*zoom-width)/2),widget.winfo_y()-((height*zoom-height)/2),95.5/speed)

    if speed>0:
        for width_,height_ in itertools.zip_longest(frange(width,width*zoom,speed),frange(height,height*zoom,speed)):
            widget.configure(width=width_,height=height_)
    elif speed<0:
        for width_,height_ in zip(frange(width,width*zoom,speed),frange(height,height*zoom,speed)):
            widget.configure(width=width_,height=height_)

root=customtkinter.CTk()
root.configure(bg='grey')
root.geometry('1200x675')

#-----
red_frame=customtkinter.CTkLabel(root,150,150,10,fg_color='red')
red_frame.place(x=60,y=230)
red_frame.bind('<Enter>', lambda event:hover_zoom(red_frame,1.2,2))
red_frame.bind('<Leave>', lambda event:hover_zoom(red_frame,0.8,-2))

root.mainloop()
```

i was expecting it to come back to its original position after the cursor is off of the widget

Comment: for *just starting with programming* you do quite a lot with your code. However, tkinter is not threadsafe on its own and you shouldn't utilize these big threads when you could use `widget.after` anyway.

Comment: After changing it to use `tkinter.Tk` and `tkinter.Label`, I just needed to change `widget.configure(width=width_,height=height_)` to `widget.configure(width=int(width_),height=int(height_))`

Comment: @Thingamabobs well not exactly just starting, its been 3 weeks, my first approach was actually yo use after however since it was part of the main process the entire window became unresponsive for the entire time the animation was going on which is far from ideal. also, converting the coordinates to integers also doesn't seem to help unfortunately.

Comment: Well it does get bigger and smaller for me. Another issue is apparently your math, cause changing values ends up in a mess for me too. But that's your issue to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Threading is not very effective in tkinter as I've seen.

My understanding is : binding <'Enter'> works slightly in a different manner than binding <'Leave'> especially where threading is involved.

For instance, when you enter the widget, the zooming may continue to work whereas while leaving the widget, the moment you leave, the zooming may stop. (And mouse movement is manual which happens without our consciousness)

So, In the following line, instead of keeping the speed -2 if you change the speed to -20 it should work. The corrected code is as follows:

```
red_frame.bind('<Leave>', lambda event:hover_zoom(red_frame,0.8,-20))
```

Another suggestion:

Instead of binding <'Enter'> and <'Leave">, What if you bind <'Button-4'>  (mouse the scroll up) and <'Button-5'>(mouse scroll down) to the respective functions.

Great effort being a beginner to the programming!